# JQuery Onclick Alert not showing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get JQuery to do something when the below is clicked:

```
<li>
<center>
<div class="iradio_square-aero">
<label class="lg" style="padding-left:0 !important"> Joint</label>
</center>
</li>
```

So you code I'm using is:

```
$('.iradio_square-aero').click(function() {

    alert('clicked');

});
```

The problem is I'm not getting any alerts.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Here is the code copied direct from the browser via firebug:

```
<li>
<center>
<div class="iradio_square-aero">
<input class="required" type="radio" value="joint" name="policy_type" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
</div>
<label class="label_gender" style="padding-left:0 !important"> Joint</label>
</center>
</li>
```

**UPDATE: The problem seems to arrive what using "jquery.wizard.js" script. As when it's on it stops working.**

Comment: Any errors in console..? Especially `$ not defined`..? Have your code wrapped inside a ready handler..?

Comment: No, no errors in the console

Comment: Have you included jQuery library?

Comment: <div> not closed html is not correct.

Comment: Yes, I've got an alert in the document ready part just to show jquery is loading

Comment: It seems to work for me in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2Tte/)... Are you sure that this is the exact code you are using?

Comment: I'm added some code copied from firebug

Comment: which version of jquery library you are using?

Comment: conflict with prototype library? what is returned by typing $ in the console?

Answer (score 0):

```
It Works Fine you can check here. Just check the jquery library path in your head section.
It may goes wrong.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvJb9/

Comment: How do you know, that he included jQuery library to his project? Your JSFiddle working, but you don't know, if he using the same code as you

Comment: I can see that but mine is not. I'm copied the code directly from firebug

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code just check the library you are referring in the head section and check you are loading your script after jquery is loading.

Answer (score 0):

What you are *probably* doing wrong is not wrapping your JavaScript code inside a jQuery document ready, and having it above the HTML at the same time.

When the browser parses the document, the JavaScript will then get executed before the HTML has been parsed fully, and your jQuery selector `$('.iradio_square-aero')` will have a length of 0.

Change the JavaScript code to the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('.iradio_square-aero').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm already wrapping it in a document ready, just didn't paste it here

Comment: @SidM you have't include jquery in your fiddle. see [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjJ5p/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Check these two jQuery fiddle, your code works fine as soon as I include jQuery in my code

[fiddle with jQuery included](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/CvJb9/1/) and [fiddle without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/CvJb9/2/)

I used your this code for fiddles

```
<li>
<center>
<div class="iradio_square-aero">
<input class="required" type="radio" value="joint" name="policy_type" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
</div>
<label class="label_gender" style="padding-left:0 !important"> Joint</label>
</center>
</li>
```

Hence one possible reason for it to be not working might be of referencing your jquery on the page.